# Tipo de dato a retornar en una función recursiva

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando un programa en el cual cuento con un método:

```
public static void RecorridoPreorden(NodoT Raiz)
{
    if (Raiz != null)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}, ", Raiz.Informacion);
        RecorridoPreorden(Raiz.NodoIzquierdo);
        RecorridoPreorden(Raiz.NodoDerecho);
    }

}
```

Sin embargo quiero que el contenido de esa función (que son números enteros) se almacene en una variable string para posteriormente imprimirla en pantalla (es necesario que la función sea de tipo string al convertirla ya que hago uso de ella posteriormente):

```
string almacenar="";
almacenar=RecorridoPreorden(Raiz);
```

Sé que tengo un error que inmediatamente el compilador me marca:
no se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'void' en 'string'

Mi problema es ¿cómo hago la conversión en este caso o que es conveniente hacer?

Comment: RecorridoPreorden devuelve void (se ve en la definición del método y en el error). Si quieres hacer que devuelva un string tienes que cambiar ese void por string y dentro, tendrás que poner un return con lo que quieras devolver.

Comment: Al no devolver un valor y teniendo en cuenta la respuesta de @Andrespengineer, puedes mirar el paso de parámetros con out, igual te puede ser de utilidad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como dice el error:

> no se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'void' en 'string'.

No se puede porque una función `void` es una función que no retorna un valor. Ahora bien, el problema está en que tampoco puedes retornar un valor independiente, porque tu función es recursiva y haces varias llamadas.

Tu función se llamará tantas veces como casos posibles haya en ella. En tu función recursiva, tu caso de ruptura es:

```
if (Raiz != null)
```

Por lo que tienes todas las condiciones para evitar un ciclo infinito.

Tu solución es crear una variable string global e ir concatenandos los valores del recorrido en Pre-Orden del Árbol:

```
private string ValoresPreOrden = "";
```

Luego en tu función recursiva, dentro del if:

```
. . .

ValoresPreOrden += Raiz.Informacion.ToString();

. . .
```

Y ya al concluir el ciclo obtendras los valores en esa variable, puedes añadir cualquier separador como espacios o comas para tener una mejor vista del resultado.

Recuerda que si manejas una sola instancia de la clase y quieres obtener el recorrido de un nuevo arbol, debes limpiar la variable `ValoresPreOrden` volviendola una cadena `""` nuevamente, antes de llamar nuevamente la función recursiva.

Comment: Por qué dices que al ser una función recursiva no se puede retornar valor? De hecho, casi todas las funciones recursivas se basan en ir devolviendo el valor "acumulado".

Comment: @Pikoh, aqui no se puede retornar un valor. Porque va a detener la secuencia. Hace 2 llamadas recursivas. Es decir, para lograr lo que quiere.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que tu funcion es un Void, osea un metodo que no retorna valor 
para que retorne valor tienes dos opciones :

convertir tu método a un String, o crear parámetros out.

lo ideal aqui es que cambiar tu metodo de void a string

```
 public static string RecorridoPreorden(NodoT Raiz)
```

en lugar de

```
  public static void RecorridoPreorden(NodoT Raiz)
```

ahora que tu método contiene un tipo de dato, cada vez que invoques al método debes de retornar un valor

```
string ri = RecorridoPreorden(Raiz.NodoIzquierdo);
string re = RecorridoPreorden(Raiz.NodoDerecho);
return ri + re;

if raiz = null

return raiz.informacion
```